# How to remove column from arrayList or array in java?

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to limit the view of larger array list to smaller one.

It is not a two dimension necessarily but that is also fine.

I want to remove the whole column data and create smaller arrayList.

*Is there a way to do it?*

Comment: An example would clarify your question so that we can understand what exactly you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Since java 8 exist [Stream.flatMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-), which is well suited for such situations.

```
List<List<Data>> twoDimensionArray...;
List<Data> smallArray = Arrays.stream(twoDimensionArray).flatMap(Arrays::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use    arraylist.remove(element) method to loop through the index of the column to remove the data.